# Adding a new key value pair to a JSON object where key has a random ID

Tags: php, json, object

I basically know how to add a new key value pair to JSON through PHP like:

```
$json->newObject = "value";
```

What I can't however figure out is how to give the key of the pair, a random ID.

I've tried something like:

```
$id = rand(99, 9999);
$json["newObject" . $id] = "value";
```

With an error of: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/methodjs/public_html/projects/chat/send.php on line 8`

And:

```
$id = rand(99, 9999);
$json->("newObject" . $id) = "value";
```

With an error of: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /home/methodjs/public_html/projects/chat/send.php on line 8`

There must be some simple way to do this, I hope. Thanks for any help.

### ***SORRY FOR THE DUBLICATE***

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
$json->{"newObject".$id} = "value";
```

The feature is called [variable properties](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). It lets you assign and get properties from an object in PHP using strings and variables.

Comment: Thank you! You learn something new everyday(:

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$json = "{}";
$json = json_decode($json);

$json->newObject = "value";

$id = rand(99, 9999);
$json->{"newObject" . $id} = "value";

$json->array = array(mt_rand(),mt_rand());

print_r($json);
```

Output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [newObject] => value
    [newObject1764] => value
    [array] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1176886102
            [1] => 1306108513
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you! You learn something new everyday(: